# REST api get the source of request

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile, backend

is there a way to know for a given REST request the name of the application mobile(source) from where the request is coming ?

Comment: What do you mean by source? You can debug the response and look what information you get. Do you mean the IP of the answering server?

Comment: I have to applications ... application A and B
In my back end, I want to know from where the request is coming ? without hardcode the name of the app in the request body

Comment: This is one of the use of API key. Using the API key, the backend can track, restrict the requests... for example: who is requesting, how many requests are coming and so on.

Comment: If your applications don't identify themselve and run on the same server they might look the same in the response, but you can debug responses from both applications and look if you see something to identify them. The easiest way if you have control over the backend is to add a header for each application and identify the applications with the header

Comment: thanks for help guys .... well using web application I can identify the source of request by their domaine name in the header. what I'm looking for is a way to do same thing with mobile app .... @DominikWuttke you mean to add header in the front end so the back end willl know from which app the request is coming from